# Discord.js sending more than 1 attachments in a message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was making a command that was supposed to send attachments and a normal message to a channel it works normally with one attachment but when someone uses the command with more than 2 attachments it will send them in separate messages which is annoying how can I change it to make all attachments in one message?

```js
if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
    message.attachments.forEach((Attachment) => {
        message.client.channels.cache.get(order.channelID).send(`Hi <@${order.userID}> I'm ${order.chefmention} and here is your order.  Remember you can use \`.feedback [Feedback]\` to give us feedback on how we did.`, {
            files: [Attachment],
        });
    });
} else {
    return message.reply("Please attach an attachment while using the command.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`files` (a property of [`MessageOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions)) accepts an array of [`FileOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/FileOptions) as well. That means you can just include all the attachments sent in the message very easily like this:

```js
if (message.author.bot) return false;
if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
    message.channel.send(`Hi ${message.author} [...]`, {
        files: message.attachments.array(),
    });
}
```